# Change ripple color of icon imageview using ActionButton styling

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to change the color of the ripple effect to white (rather than the default dark grey).

Each ImageView has `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"` to achieve a ripple effect.

I've tried applying `tint` / `backgroundtint` / creating a custom style in `styles.xml` - none have an effect on the color of the ripple.

Example of current effect:

[image: Action button example of ripple effect]

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/item_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#333333"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/info_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_info_outline_white_24dp"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/share_btn"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/share_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_white_24dp"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/share_btn"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I posted an solutin, but Im not sure if style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton" will add an ripple to your image view at all. If it doesnt, or if my answer doesnt help, I will edit it with custom ripple implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a theme like this:

```
<style name="RippleColorTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/yourRippleColor</item>
</style>
```

And apply this theme to your image view like this:

```
<ImageView
    ...
    android:theme="@style/RippleColorTheme" />
```

This should change the color of your ripple effect on that particular view.

Comment: I had to use ```parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"``` in my style. Didn't seem to work with ```parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar"```. If you update your answer to reflect this I will mark it as accepted. Thank you :)